# Query where alternate scenarios could take place

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I am checking for the first instance of a status. The issue is that the status can vary in some circumstances.

For example I have records like the following and the correct record would be ID=12 because it is the first instance the item was actually Covered. 10 appears so, but then it changed to Available again so would not be the final position the record is set to Covered.

| ID | PreviousValue | CurrentValue | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Available | Covered | 2024-03-01 |
| 11 | Covered | Available | 2024-03-02 |
| 12 | Available | Covered | 2024-03-03 |
| 13 | Covered | Dispatched | 2024-03-04 |

The other complexity is that in same cases I may have the following where there is no Available instance, it just starts as Covered and I would need to know that, that is the record I am looking for.

| ID | PreviousValue | CurrentValue | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Covered | Dispatched | 2024-03-04 |
| 11 | Dispatched | In-Transit | 2024-03-05 |

I tried something like this, but it does not seem to return the correct record from the first recordset above.

```
select *
from loads_fieldupdates 
where theField = 'loadStatus'
and loadid = 261574
and (
        /* most common scenario */
        (previousFieldVal LIKE 'Available%' AND theFieldVal LIKE 'Covered%')
        OR
        /* case where load was duped so started as covered but not went back to available */
        (previousFieldVal LIKE 'Covered%' AND theFieldVal NOT LIKE 'Available%')
)
order by dateCreated desc
```

Comment: So you need the *most recent* row when CurrentValue was Covered, and if that does not exist, the most recent time when PreviousValue was Covered. Incidentally, storing the PreviousValue seems like data duplication. PreviousValue can be gotten using [`lag`](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-lag/).

Comment: Correct, except if Covered is never current value. Record was initially created set to Covered so the only tracking is when it gets changed the first time. I probably do not need to store the previous value but it simplified development as a visual.

Comment: You should attempt to avoid storing data that can be calculated...

Comment: It seems like a design flaw that you directly store the initial value. Also that a value can only change once per day. Changing `DateCreated` to a timestamp might help. Storing just `value` and `changed_at` would make this easier.

Comment: The record can be duplicated in the application so the starting status needs to be noted. I have never used the lag function but it seems worth investigating in this instance. Also, a timestamp is used, I just entered dates for the example data. I see what you are saying. If initially I created the record as Covered in the field val and set previous to NULL, it would accomplish a much more basic log of changes

Comment: @mackaboogie "*The record can be duplicated in the application so the starting status needs to be noted.*" Sorry, I'm not sure what that means. Could you add an example? Otherwise, I would suggest filling in the missing starting data. Then your queries become simpler.

Comment: You are correct. The method of storing the data is causing the querying problem. I will convert my table data to only use the value and timestamp and that will probably allow me to just pull most recent record of Covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a query where I am checking for the first instance of a status.

Seems like you're checking for the *latest* instance of a status.

It seems like the problem statement can be simplified to:

1. Find the latest row where CurrentValue is Covered.
2. If no such row exists, find the latest row where PreviousValue is Covered.

We need three pieces of information.

1. Distinct IDs of things (in your query this is loadid).
2. For each thing, latest row where CurrentValue is Covered.
3. For each thing, latest row where PreviousValue is Covered.

We make a sub-select to get answers to each question, left join them together, and pick the first one which is not null.

```
with currently_covered as (
  select
  *,
  row_number() over(
    partition by ThingId
    order by DateCreated desc
  ) as rownum
  from field_updates
  where CurrentValue = 'Covered'
), previously_covered as (
  select
  *,
  row_number() over(
    partition by ThingId
    order by DateCreated desc
  ) as rownum
  from field_updates
  where PreviousValue = 'Covered'
), distinct_things as (
  select distinct thingid
  from field_updates
)
select
  -- If a thing is not currently covered, cc.id will be null.
  dt.thingid, coalesce(cc.id, pc.id) as id
from distinct_things dt
left join currently_covered cc on dt.thingid = cc.thingid and cc.rownum = 1
left join previously_covered pc on dt.thingid = pc.thingid and pc.rownum = 1
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/vRlJ-og7).

---

As discussed in the comments, there are design flaws making this query more difficult than it needs to be.

1. There is no need to store PreviousValue, that is data duplication.
2. If the initial state is stored, the problem goes away.

The real solution should be to update the table so the initial state is stored with a PreviousState of null. This requires PreviousState to be nullable, and we have to make up a timestamp.

```
with distinct_things as (
  select distinct thingid
  from field_updates
), first_values as (
  select
    thingid, previousvalue, datecreated,
    row_number() over (
      partition by thingid
      order by datecreated asc
    ) as rownum
  from field_updates
)
insert into field_updates(thingid, previousvalue, currentvalue, datecreated)
select dt.thingid, null, fv.previousvalue, dateadd(day, -1, fv.datecreated)
from distinct_things dt
left join first_values fv on dt.thingid = fv.thingid and rownum = 1
```

Then the PreviousValue can be dropped. Use `lag` to get the previous value.

```
select
  *,
  lag(currentvalue) over(
    partition by thingid
    order by datecreated
  ) as PreviousValue
from field_updates
order by thingid, datecreated;
```

Now your query is much simpler. We just need to find the latest row where CurrentValue is Covered.

```
with currently_covered as (
  select
  *,
  row_number() over(
    partition by ThingId
    order by DateCreated desc
  ) as rownum
  from field_updates
  where CurrentValue = 'Covered'
)
select *
from currently_covered
where rownum = 1
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/PiDkUHV9).

Comment: Excellent solution. I have changed my table design and dropped the previous value.

Comment: @mackaboogie Great! I'm glad it worked out well.